# How can I add workspaces (tabs groups) to PhpStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, workspace, jetbrains-ide

Is there exists workspaces like in NuSphere phped (saved opened files) inside one project in PhpStorm?

Maybe any plugin exists? I need opened files profiles within one project (tabs groups)...

Comment: If I understand you correctly -- it's called Context in PhpStorm -- https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/switching-between-contexts.html?search=context

Comment: Yes, it is Context in PhpStorm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Such functionality is called "Contexts" in PhpStorm and you can switch between them using `Tools | Tasks & Contexts | Load Context`.

More on this in official Help pages: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/switching-between-contexts.html?search=context

---

**P.S.** If you are using VCS in your project and you are using [integration with an Issue Tracking System in PhpStorm](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Integration+with+an+Issue+Tracking+System+in+PhpStorm) then IDE will load your tabs that you had open when last time worked on that particular ticket/task.